# Django doesn't display that user exist

Tags: python, django, authentication

I learned Django from course but I have a problem. I can register and login. If password's doesn't match it display validate error but it doesn't display an error if user exist. OK. My view's method looks like this

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            sex = form.cleaned_data['sex']

            user = Account.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password, sex=sex)
            user.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Udało Ci się zarejestrować!')
            return redirect('register')

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

My forms

```
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Enter Password',
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
        'class': "form-control"
    }))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username', 'sex', 'email', 'password']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Password doesn not match!'
            )
```

And models

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, sex, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have an username')
        if not sex:
            raise ValueError('User must have an checked sex')
        
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            sex = sex
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length = 5,
        choices = [
            ('Man', 'Man'),
            ('Woman', 'Woman'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
        ]

    )

    #required
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    #LOGIN FIELDS
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'sex']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

For me is a little bit strange code because valdiation rules is in a few places but it is from course. If I submit my form and another user with this same email exist it doesn't display error, only register form. Why?

Why this code doesn't display if user exist? Could you fix that?

Comment: You haven't set the email field as unique in your model.

Comment: I don't understand. In this model I used `unique=True`. Colud you show me how fix my code?

Comment: You're right, I didn't see it. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299435/how-can-i-show-an-error-message-if-the-username-already-exists-for-creating-an-a